Some windows can't be resized at their edges ever since upgrading to 24.04.1 LTS
Since upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04, certain applications cannot be resized by placing the cursor at the window's edge. I can still resize them in other ways (maximizing them, dragging the window to the edge of the screen, using alt+F8, etc).
I've seen others describe the same problem (One example: Cant resize windows) but most of them appear to be using Wayland, while I'm on X11. I've disabled all gnome extensions, but that hasn't helped.
Applications I can't resize:

Firefox
Chromium
Discord
VS Code
Spotify
Audacious
VLC player (Though I can use the corner resize that's part of the VLC interface.)
FileZilla (Though I can use the corner resize that's part of the Filezilla interface.)

Applications I CAN resize

Thunderbird
Terminal
gedit
Steam
Files


Launchpad bug 2042301 has xorg sessions slow to display window contents. I just noticed also on a firefox window, neither the drag nor resize worked either for 30-40 seconds, then things worked normally. Wayland works without the delay.

I'm not certain I understand what you mean, but this is not an intermittent issue. It happens with new windows, and windows that have been open for several weeks of uptime.
